# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable after filtering datetime

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to write a django-orm to filter datetime field and some other fields. then convert it to pandas dataframe. 
this code works correctly :

```
order_order_df = 
pd.DataFrame(list(Order.objects.filter(canceled=False, 
order_time__isnull=False).values()))
```

but this code is not working:

```
order_order_df = 
pd.DataFrame(list(Order.objects.filter(canceled=False, 
order_time__isnull=False, 
order_time__gte=datetime(2018, 10, 1)).values()))
```

why did this happen? how can I filter datetime and convert it to pandas correctly?
NOTE:
I know it can be filtered properly after converting to pandas but I need it to be done by queryset here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you've imported `datetime` like

```
import datetime
```

so you can't invoke `datetime()` – you'll want `datetime.datetime`:

```
order_order_df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        Order.objects.filter(
            canceled=False,
            order_time__isnull=False,
            order_time__gte=datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1),
        ).values()
    )
)
```

Comment: ok, by using the code you wrote it raise this error:

_AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!_

Comment: That's a different question then, and hard to answer without seeing what exactly is giving that error (i.e. we'll need a traceback). But really, ask it in another question.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent these errors:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable after filtering datetime
>   AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string

use this code:

```
order_order_df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        Order.objects.filter(
            canceled=False,
            order_time__isnull=False,
            ).exclude(
            order_time__lte=datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1)
        ).values()
    )
)
```